# Regex in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create a Jenkins pipeline step that should only run for certain Gerrit projects. In particular, for all projects where the variable GERRIT_PROJECT starts with "platform/zap".
Sadly, I suffer from a lack of skills in Groovy.

This is what I got so far:

```
stage ('zap') {
        when {
            expression {
                isMatch = env.GERRIT_PROJECT =~ /^platform\/zap/
                return isMatch
            }
        }
        steps {
            build job: 'Zap', parameters: [
                string(name: 'ZAP_PROJECT', value: env.GERRIT_PROJECT)
            ]
        }
    }
```

In other words, the stage should be executed for "platform/zap/os" but not for "app/hello".

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `String.startsWith(str)` that returns `true` if `env.GERRIT_PROJECT` starts with `platform/zap`.

```groovy
stage ('zap') {
    when {
        expression {
            env.GERRIT_PROJECT?.startsWith("platform/zap")
        }
    }
    steps {
        build job: 'Zap', parameters: [
            string(name: 'ZAP_PROJECT', value: env.GERRIT_PROJECT)
        ]
    }
}
```

To avoid NPE if `env.GERRIT_PROJECT` is null for some reason, you can use NPE-safe operator `?.` to invoke `startsWith` method.

The alternative solution that uses Groovy's exact match operator with regex could look like this:

```groovy
stage ('zap') {
    when {
        expression {
            env.GERRIT_PROJECT ==~ /^platform\/zap(.*)$/
        }
    }
    steps {
        build job: 'Zap', parameters: [
            string(name: 'ZAP_PROJECT', value: env.GERRIT_PROJECT)
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You're a star! Both of your solutions work as promised.

Comment: Champion. Been looking for a solution like this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/
Section environment:

> **environment**
>   Execute the stage when the specified environment variable
>   is set to the given value, for example: when { environment name:
>   'DEPLOY_TO', value: 'production' }

Maybe this can help?

Comment: Useful hint, thank you. But it will only handle full matches.